# RegExp match more than two empty lines

Tags: regex

I am using Emacs and one of its modes separates the code into groups of smaller codes if there is an empty line between lines. It uses `^\s-*$` regular expression as a matching line. However, I want to configure it to behave as separate to groups **when there is 2 or more empty lines** between lines. What is the regular expression for this?

For example right now:

```
*Group 1 starts*
Line1
Line2
*Group 1 ends*
--empty line
*Group 2 starts*
Line3
*Group 2 ends*
--empty line
--empty line
*Group 3 starts*
Line4
Line5
*Group 3 ends*
```

I want it to look like this:

```
*Group 1 starts*
Line1
Line2
--empty line
Line3
*Group 1 ends*
--empty line
--empty line
*Group 2 starts*
Line4
Line5
*Group 2 ends*
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC `\s-*$` is the expression of your separator. In this case it matches a line composed of any number (0 works as well) of whitespaces (in this particular Regex implementation matched by `\s-`). `$` marks the end of the line.
If you want to separate when there are two or more of such lines, try using a quantifier:

```
(\s-*$){2,}
```

Edit: typo and taking @The fourth bird's remark into consideration, you should still escape parenthesis and brackets.

Comment: I have tried ```(\s-*$){2,}``` but it did not work.

Comment: Also, when I just try ```(\s-*$)``` it also does not separate like ```\s-*$```.

Comment: Interesting, how do you activate this split in emacs? Also could you try `(?:\s-*$)`

Comment: I am using VHDL-mode, and the options I am interested in are related with aligning. Also, I tried ```(?:\s-*$)``` but it did not work as intended. Even if I separate some of the lines with lots of empty lines above and below these lines, these lines with above and below aligned together.

Comment: based on your comments and @The fourth bird's input, my last guess would be `\(?:\s-*$\)\{2,\}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a repeated group, but looking at [this page](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression) you have to escape the parenthesis and the curly's.

Where according to the documentation, the `\s-` means:

```
\s-   whitespace character
```

For example

```
\(\s-*$\)\{2,\}
```

Comment: ```\(\s-*$\)\{2,\}```  I tried this but it does separate every line individually I think.

Comment: @efe373 Perhaps what is stated on this page https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultilineRegexp using 2 times `C-q C-j`

Comment: VHDL-mode of the Emacs separates the entire code into groups. Each group is defined as  'A group of code lines is a region of consecutive lines between two lines that match the regexp in option 'vhdl-align-group-separate''. The option 'vhdl-align-group-separate' is ```^\s-*$```, and this separates every new line. Due to the coding style of the company that I work for, I need to separate the code into group if there is more than 2 new lines between groups. So, ```C-q C-j``` does not work for me I assume.

Comment: @The fourth bird good catch! this a peculiar regex implementation...